# Meeting request properties not settable in EWS SOAP calls?

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices, meeting-request

I (re)create (recurrent) events in Exchange Server talking to Exchange Web Services with pure SOAP calls.

When these events are actually meeting requests I try to maintain some meeting properties that were previously retrieved, so I put them in the `CreateItem` call:

```
AllowNewTimeProposal
AppointmentReplyTime
ConferenceType
IsCancelled
IsOnlineMeeting
IsResponseRequested
MeetingWorkspaceURL
MeetingRequestWasSent
MyResponseType
NetShowURL
Organizer
OptionalAttendees
RequiredAttendees
Resources
```

At first I got the error `Set action is invalid for property` for the properties `IsCancelled` and `IsOnlineMeeting`, and thought *O, these are probably set automatically*, but now I even get them for the `Organizer` on the event where the user is the organizer.

**What is going on?**
Are all these meeting properties not settable in a `CreateItem` call?
Have I just accidentally bumped into three that are not settable - where can I find a list of what is actually settable (the docs at e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa580675%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx do mention the occasional read-only element, but not these)?

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header>
  <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
  <typ:TimeZoneContext>
     <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
  </typ:TimeZoneContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <mes:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToNone">
      <mes:SavedItemFolderId>
         <typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
            <typ:Mailbox>
               <typ:EmailAddress>jan@TimeTellBV567.onmicrosoft.com</typ:EmailAddress>
            </typ:Mailbox>
         </typ:DistinguishedFolderId>
      </mes:SavedItemFolderId>
      <mes:Items>
         <typ:CalendarItem>
           <typ:Subject>recuir MODI</typ:Subject>
           <typ:Body BodyType="Text"></typ:Body>
           <typ:Categories>
             <typ:String>TimeTell</typ:String>
           </typ:Categories>
           <typ:ReminderIsSet>false</typ:ReminderIsSet>
           <typ:Start>2015-07-23T11:30:00.000+02:00</typ:Start>
           <typ:End>2015-07-23T12:00:00.000+02:00</typ:End>
           <typ:IsAllDayEvent>false</typ:IsAllDayEvent>
           <typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
           <typ:Location>daar</typ:Location>
           <typ:IsResponseRequested>true</typ:IsResponseRequested>
           <typ:MyResponseType>Organizer</typ:MyResponseType>
           <typ:Organizer>
             <typ:Mailbox>
               <typ:Name>Jan</typ:Name>
               <typ:EmailAddress>jan@somewhere.onmicrosoft.com</typ:EmailAddress>
               <typ:RoutingType>SMTP</typ:RoutingType>
             </typ:Mailbox>
           </typ:Organizer>
           <typ:RequiredAttendees>
             <typ:Attendee>
               <typ:Mailbox>
                 <typ:Name>Ben</typ:Name>
                 <typ:EmailAddress>ben@somewhere.onmicrosoft.com</typ:EmailAddress>
                 <typ:RoutingType>SMTP</typ:RoutingType>
               </typ:Mailbox>
               <typ:ResponseType>Unknown</typ:ResponseType>
             </typ:Attendee>
           </typ:RequiredAttendees>
           <typ:Recurrence>
             <typ:WeeklyRecurrence>
               <typ:Interval>1</typ:Interval>
               <typ:DaysOfWeek>Thursday</typ:DaysOfWeek>
             </typ:WeeklyRecurrence>
             <typ:NoEndRecurrence>
               <typ:StartDate>2015-07-23+01:00</typ:StartDate>
             </typ:NoEndRecurrence>
           </typ:Recurrence>
           <typ:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
           <typ:ConferenceType>0</typ:ConferenceType>
           <typ:AllowNewTimeProposal>true</typ:AllowNewTimeProposal>
           <typ:IsOnlineMeeting>false</typ:IsOnlineMeeting>
         </typ:CalendarItem>
      </mes:Items>
   </mes:CreateItem>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<Envelope>
  <Header>
    <ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="213" MinorBuildNumber="21" Version="V2_47"/>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <CreateItemResponse>
      <ResponseMessages>
        <CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <MessageText>Set action is invalid for property.</MessageText>
          <ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidPropertySet</ResponseCode>
          <DescriptiveLinkKey>0</DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <MessageXml>
            <FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Organizer"/>
          </MessageXml>
          <Items/>
        </CreateItemResponseMessage>
      </ResponseMessages>
    </CreateItemResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I'm currently testing with the organizer in his own calander, against Office 365, but as you can see from the request I want this to work from `Exchange2007_SP1` up.

Answer (score 1):

*(Answering my own question)*

Mmm, that question was a bit of a false alarm, but I'm leaving it here because the information is hard to find.

It turns out that the properties I attempted to modify **were indeed all read-only**: `IsCancelled`, `IsOnlineMeeting`, `MeetingRequestWasSent` and `Organizer`.
Quoting Kim Brand from an answer in [the 'Exchange EWS set CalendarItem Organizer' post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3183b77b-b190-4e42-8d12-2f1e47317369/exchange-ews-set-calendaritem-organizer?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) at the MS Exchange Development Forum:

> Organizer is a read-only property, which means that you can't "set" that property. That's why you are seeing the error message "Set action is invalid for property".

> Organizer is the party responsible for coordinating meeting attendence, and its value gets automatically set to the user that creates the CalendarItem (unless Delegate Access is used).

When I leave the above properties out of my `CreateItem` call, it works. A `GetItem` on the created/updated appointment shows that `Organizer` is indeed set:

```
<t:Organizer>
   <t:Mailbox>
      <t:Name>Jan</t:Name>
      <t:EmailAddress>/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=A9403513C6AA40E68E05776BFEA9C117-JAN</t:EmailAddress>
      <t:RoutingType>EX</t:RoutingType>
      <t:MailboxType>OneOff</t:MailboxType>
   </t:Mailbox>
</t:Organizer>
```

[Edited to add]:
It *is* possible to set readonly properties through MAPI, see my other post
[How to 'set' read-only calendar appointment properties (related to meetings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678040/how-to-set-read-only-calendar-appointment-properties-related-to-meetings])

Comment: EWS programmers using pure SOAP-requests seem to be a dying breed :) Great info Jan!

Comment: @Tholle That's the result of having to do all this from Delphi (XE2), in which I never got the WDSL imported code to work.