# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment IsOnlineMeeting Set action is invalid for Property

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Trying to create a calendar event in exchange using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment. Everything works fine until I set the IsOnlineMeeting property to True.  This results in the error "Set action is invalid for Property".

In the Appointment object this property is marked as "settable".  I'm able to set the IsResponseRequested property to true with no issues.  Has anyone experienced this issue before with IsOnlineMeeting property?

```
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this is an online meeting.
 public bool IsOnlineMeeting { get; set; }
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a value indicating whether responses are requested when invitations are sent for this meeting.
public bool IsResponseRequested { get; set; }
```

Comment: In the underlying EWS properties IsOnlineMeeting is indeed readonly. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678040/how-to-set-read-only-calendar-appointment-properties-related-to-meetings  I have no idea if the library you use  (you should add the appropriate tag) is supposed to use the MAPI Extended Properties under the hood, or if the documentation is incorrect. Maybe you can access the MAPI Extended Properties via another way?