# Set online meeting properties to Appointment object using EWS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, exchangewebservices, skype, ucma

I develop MVC application which communicates with corporate Exchange server.
**Major features are:**
1. Create an appointment in the user calendar
2. Create Lync\Skype for business meeting
3. Set Lync\Skype for business meeting URL to the appointment

**What is done:**
1. Using EWS application creates Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment object and saves it to the Exchange server. It's simple.
2. Using UCMA application creates Lync\Skype for business meeting and gets URL to this meeting. It's simple too
**3. I can't find any information about this point. Appointment object has properties IsOnlineMeeting and JoinOnlineMeetingUrl. But it's read-only.**

Please, help me.
How can I do it? Maybe it's a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link mentioned, You should be able to use MAPI Extended Properties.

[How to 'set' read-only calendar appointment properties (related to meetings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678040/how-to-set-read-only-calendar-appointment-properties-related-to-meetings)

[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment IsOnlineMeeting Set action is invalid for Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254066/microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-appointment-isonlinemeeting-set-action-is-in)

Comment: Tank you. But:  
XML Scheme for property update is  
<ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertySetId="" PropertyTag="" PropertyName="" PropertyId="" PropertyType="" />  

What are the property values for my question?